# How to safely quit logcheck which is taking up 75% of my CPU for hours?

Tags: debian, process, cpu, cpu-usage, logcheck

`logcheck` has had `grep` running for a couple hours now and it's still not finished. How can I find out why it's taking that long and how can I gracefully quit it (so that it won't skip any logs but simply processes them at a later point)?

I'm using Debian 9.1 with KDE. Typically it has 1 process that takes up 25% of my CPU and runs for a couple minutes. It started like that as well but now it's 3 processes and 75% and as said has been running for hours. My syslog file is about 500MB in size.

I need to quit it for 3 reasons:

- My PC is too loud
- Plasma seems to have crashed - the taskbar and widgets are frozen. I can still use dolphin and so on but not very conveniently.
- I'd like to use the CPU for other things

---

I checked `/var/log/` and found that the largest file is syslog.1 with 3.5 GB.

More or less the upper half of the messages are:

```
pulseaudio[2159]: [alsa-sink-USB Audio] alsa-sink.c: Failed to set hardware parameters: Input/output error  
kernel: [59463.466760] usb 1-11: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)  
kernel: [59463.467203] usb 1-11: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)  
kernel: [59463.467631] usb 1-11: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)  
kernel: [59463.468323] usb 1-11: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)  
kernel: [59463.468753] usb 1-11: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)  
kernel: [59463.469182] usb 1-11: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)  
kernel: [59463.469813] usb 1-11: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)  
kernel: [59463.470261] usb 1-11: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
```

and the lower half of the messages look like:

```
dbus-daemon[1916]: Rejected: destination has a full message queue, 0 matched rules; type="signal", sender=":1.9" (uid=1000 pid=2062 comm="kded5 [kdeinit5]                                  ") interface="org.kde.KDirNotify" member="FilesAdded" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (uid=1000 pid=2113 comm="/usr/bin/plasmashell --shut-up ")  
dbus-daemon[1916]: Rejected: destination has a full message queue, 0 matched rules; type="signal", sender=":1.9" (uid=1000 pid=2062 comm="kded5 [kdeinit5]                                  ") interface="org.kde.KDirNotify" member="FilesAdded" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (uid=1000 pid=2113 comm="/usr/bin/plasmashell --shut-up ")  
dbus-daemon[1916]: Rejected: destination has a full message queue, 0 matched rules; type="signal", sender=":1.9" (uid=1000 pid=2062 comm="kded5 [kdeinit5]                                  ") interface="org.kde.KDirNotify" member="FilesAdded" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (uid=1000 pid=2113 comm="/usr/bin/plasmashell --shut-up ")
```

I don't really know what these messages mean. I copied files between locations before. I did not have problems with the audio. Plasmashell didn't work for a while.

Comment: Find the process id of each logcheck program and use `kill -stop` on them to make them pause. Use `lsof -p ` on each pid to see what files it has open. Perhaps something is creating lots of log messages, and that is the true cause of the problem. You can use `kill -cont` to continue the processes.

Comment: would you please add the output of `sudo du -sh /var/log` to the question?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I just added which file is the largest and its contents.

Comment: bluetooth?, sound/kde/dbus errors... I am not of much help there, I do not use linux as desktop

Answer (score 0):

As it is your workstation, I would simply uninstall logcheck.

Logcheck is part of a more elabore security setup of Linux servers, and  more useful in an enterprise setting with multiple servers, to detect, parse and mail yourself log errors.

To uninstall it do:

```
sudo apt-get remove logcheck
```

It would be advisable opening another question about the size of yours logs, or changing log rotation of some possibly installed services from weekly to daily; they must be bigger than usual for logcheck to be so busy. As @meuh says, it might be useful perusing `/var/log` to see which logs are out of control; a 500MB syslog seems a normal size, but there are more log files.